# Autocomplete Layout Not working with CompileSdk 33

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, jetbrains-ide

My problem arises when I want to run an app in debug mode with the device connected, but it told me that a library required a minimum of compileSDK 33.

When I change to this version, the autocomplete of the layout & I create on the code side does not work correctly.

I cannot create a component and fill it with its default properties, nor can I create the strings by pressing ALT + ENTER in Windows 11 OS.

When I return to CompileSDK 32, that problem no longer exists, but I cannot run the application directly if I do not update to 33.

The problem is in this library that requests it
androidx.core:core:1.9.0-beta01@aar

- Android Studio;
  Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 2
  Build #AI-212.5712.43.2112.8815526, built on July 10, 2022
  Runtime version: 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840 aarch64
  VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
  Memory: 2048M
- Operating System : macOS 13.0.1 (MAC m1 chip)

When I return to CompileSDK 32, that problem no longer exists, but I cannot run the application directly if I do not update to 33.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved in the Dolphin version of Android studio
Please update your version to the below version

Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-213.7172.25.2113.9123335, built on September 30, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.

Answer (score 0):

The XML auto complete suitable for SDK33 is present in more recent Android Studio IDEs for those versions, use for example the following versions:

[image]

For the case of Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 which is the latest update as of today this problem has not been fixed yet. And apparently it will never be fixed in Chipmunk.

IssueTracker: [enter link description here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/241460885)

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed my issue tonight. I updated my android studio to Iguana

the change my gradle build versions and a couple of other things

1st. distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.4-bin.zip in gradle wrapper

2nd. change java version to 17.0.5 in gradle settings

3rd. updated id 'com.android.application' version '8.3.0' apply false
id 'com.android.library' version '8.3.0' apply false in gradle file

4th. in build.gradle change compileSdk to 33 and targetSdk to 33

5th. add a namespace in your android tag in build.gradle.

Note! The cause of the issue is just series of incompatibilities in android stido version, gradle versions and possibly plain incompetence on the side of Android studio team. Because this happens in every build starting from version
3.3